How can I link a project to a unit test project in C#?
How can I link my project to my test project through docker since I am adjusting the dockerfile and it would be through docker commands I have this doubt if you could help me it would be of great help since I have not found any reference on that point.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-test
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["*.sln", "."]
#COPY ["portal-web/portal-web.csproj", "portal-web/."]
#COPY ["portal-web-test/portal-web-test.csproj", "portal-web-test/."]
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o ./app/build


Sorry trying to understand the ask here. Is your test project a web application that needs to be hosted in docker so that you can test your portal-web project?

This sounds like an X/Y problem. "How can I link my project to my test project through docker" doesn't really make sense. Either you execute the unit tests outside of docker (in which case you don't copy anything in prior to running the tests, and the only thing you copy in to the docker image is the main project), or you run the tests in the container (in which case you copy ALL the projects in, but only persist the main project to the next FROM layer).

if your question is how to add a reference on project into unit test project, then see dotnet add reference .. command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference
